# Is the Samsung Galaxy S4 compatible with CyanogenMod's smart card emulation (NFC)?

Tags: android, nfc, cyanogenmod, hce, contactless-smartcard

I have the Samsung Galaxy S4 and the SCM SDI010 card reader. My goal is to let the S4 emulate a smart card which then can be read by the card reader.

I tried to apply the PKI applet example described [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/10/emulating-pki-smart-card-with-cm91.html) (installing CyanogenMod 10.2, starting se-emulator on the S4 and starting the se-pki-client on my Linux PC). But the connection establishment fails with either a "SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD" or "SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD" exception on the reader side.

1. Does anyone know if the NFC chip on the S4 is supported by the CyanogeMod for card emulation?
2. Do I need to explicitly activate card emulation on the S4 which is not directly described in the tutorial above?

Best regards

Comment: Probably better posted on a different exchange site, not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

No, the CyanogenMod patches for software card emulation currently work with NXP chipsets only (the modifications affect libnfc-nxp only). Devices with Broadcom chipsets are not (yet?) supported.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that some software found out of the box on Cyanogen works with the Broadcom chip. Back in october 2012 when the article was posted, there were very few devices not shipping with NXP NFC controller. The solution would have to be patched with support for Broadcom's chip. It is possible, though, that card emulation by the host requires a new firmware.