# Simple method to emulate Mifare Desfire EV1

Tags: android, rfid, emulation

I am investigating the possibilities to emulate a mifare desfire card to simplify QA of a large authentication system.

My current ideas are:
Arduino implementation
Android implementation

I want an easy way of doing this.

I can see that cyanogenmod has done some [development](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/q/status:merged+project:CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Nfc,n,z) on this specific card.

But I also read it might be [incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497803/is-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-compatible-with-cyanogenmods-smart-card-emulation-nfc?rq=1) with the Samsung S4 which is my primary device. I can get a hold of some nexus phones if that helps. However, there seems to be some problems with [this to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220523/card-emulation-via-software-nfc/17244315#17244315)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055497/emulate-mifare-card-with-android-4-4/20068329#20068329) someone thinks emulating might be possible.

Concerning the arduino alternative, this seems a little harder to do, if the android alternative can be done. Does anybody have any experience with emulating the RFID on Android.
And in that case what phone did you use, and what software/libs?